# How to get 2 tunnels UP between OpenSwan and AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, openswan

I have a VPC and network in `eu-central-1` and one `in eu-west-1` in AWS.
The `eu-central-1` fakes my on-prem environment. There I installed and configured OpenSwan on an EC2. In `in eu-west-1` I configured a side-to-side VPN (customer gw, virtual gw, ..).

It works and tunnel1 is up. Now I try to get my 2nd tunnel up.
I added a second config:

```
conn Tunnel1
authby=secret
auto=start
left=%defaultroute
leftid=yyy
right=xxx
type=tunnel
ikelifetime=8h
keylife=1h
phase2alg=aes128-sha1;modp1024
ike=aes128-sha1;modp1024
keyingtries=%forever
keyexchange=ike
leftsubnet=192.168.0.0/16
rightsubnet=10.0.0.0/16
dpddelay=10
dpdtimeout=30
dpdaction=restart_by_peer

 conn Tunnel2
    authby=secret
    auto=start
    left=%defaultroute
    leftid=yyy
    right=zzz
    type=tunnel
    ikelifetime=8h
    keylife=1h
    phase2alg=aes128-sha1;modp1024
    ike=aes128-sha1;modp1024
    keyingtries=%forever
    keyexchange=ike
    leftsubnet=192.168.0.0/16
    rightsubnet=10.0.0.0/16
    dpddelay=10
    dpdtimeout=30
    dpdaction=restart_by_peer
```

Also added the PSK

```
xxx yyy: PSK "QbkjDdfP4sfma9nFsMwYCg6vr.C1adfds"
xxx zzz: PSK "Kfd_26YNCndfr1g2tkFIzw5dfaTxhXMx"
```

I restart IPSEC:
I see errors:

```
000 Total IPsec connections: loaded 2, active 1

"Tunnel2" #4: cannot install eroute -- it is in use for "Tunnel1" #3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `journalctl -xe | grep "Tunnel2"`  check the logs for more details. Use tools like `ip xfrm policy` and `ip xfrm state` to check the Security Policy Database (SPD) and Security Association Database (SAD) entries. Ensure that they are consistent with your configuration.